# Why the second and third ionisation enthalpy of Bismuth is more than that of Antimony?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

The first ionisation enthalpy values of Group 15 elements follows a decreasing trend due to increasing atomic size and metallic character but why do the second and third ionisation enthalpy values follow such an anomalous trend ?